# Here maps Getting attractions / places aling route

Tags: here-api

I am using the Routing service to get the route between two points. I would like to return attractions or places along or near the route, if possible. I have searched but unable to find anything that looks like it does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browse end point for the same. This endpoint provides search results for places based on different filters, such as categories or name, ranked by distance from a given search center. The only mandatory elements exposed in the response are id and position. The other elements shown in the response samples section are only dataset attributes suggestions.

https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse

For more details please check below doc. https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/index.html